# Complex non-linear function minimization with constraints using scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, minimization

This is my first ever post on stack - after a week of scratching my head I figure it's time to ask the internet.

I'm trying to minimize the output of a complex Python function, which takes in 3 (or more) coefficients for a polynomial, and returns the slope-squared of a plot which should, in an ideal world, represent a flat line.

The function is not simply mathematical - it uses the supplied polynomial to modify (by multiplication) an astronomical filter throughput curve (e.g. https://www.sdss3.org/images/camera_filters.jpg), which is then used along with model stellar atmospheres to calculate bolometric corrections, and ultimately plot the difference between a calculated and observed astronomical magnitude (dm), as a function of colour (g-r), for a bunch of stars.

Essentially, this function "getSlope()" is a black box, which takes around 12-seconds to compute the output slope for any given input polynomial.

I've been using scipy.optimize.minimize to minimize the function and find the polynomial parameters that return the flattest plot. Unfortunately, the flattest plot seems to be produced when the polynomial is returning negative values during the range of interest. This produces a fudged filter throughput curve that is at times below zero, which is not only unphysical but also screws up some of the black box calculations.

I thought that I could use the COBYLA inequality constraints to find a minimum which doesn't use negative polynomial evaluations, but it doesn't seem to be helping.

Using the function isValid(), I return +1 when the polynomial is OK within the given limits, and -1 when it is returning negative values. E.g:

```
    def isValid(poly):
        p=Polynomial(poly)
        x=np.linspace(startWL,endWL,2000)
        y=p(x)
        if np.any(y<0):
            print "returning minus one"
            return -1
        else:
            return 1
```

I then set the constraint to evaluate this function "isValid()".

```
poly = [1,0.0001,0.000000001] # polynomial parameters a1 + a2*x + a3*x^2
cons = ({'type':'ineq','fun':isValid})
res = minimize(getSlope,poly,method='COBYLA',constraints=cons,tol=1E-11)
print res
```

I had hoped that this would find a minimum which is within the constraint limits, i.e. where the polynomial is never evaluated as negative during the interval in which I am interested. However, it seems to simply find a minimum which is outside of my constraints, and then tell me as such. I.e:

```
1.97336588518e-07
returning minus one
2.16503874744e-06
returning minus one
2.40318933164e-07
returning minus one
status: 4
nfev: 80
maxcv: 1.0
success: False
fun: 2.4031893316449186e-07
x: array([  9.96886224e-01,   2.59958641e-01,  -6.85767425e-05])
message: 'Did not converge to a solution satisfying the constraints. See `maxcv` for magnitude of violation.'
```

This doesn't seem particularly helpful! I can easily tell that this solution is outside of my constraints. Am I implementing this constraint process correctly? **Is there a way to force the minimization function to find the best minimum within the constraints, even if there's a lower minimum outside of the constraints?** I'm no expert with statistics or programming, so I'm feeling rather lost. Any and all tips appreciated!

Comment: Using a *discontinuous* constraint function is probably not a good idea. You can try just returning `y`.